# Move Outlook items after certain amount of time

Tags: microsoft-outlook

I am attempting to set a rule, or a policy, to move items with my Inbox, to a specific folder, labelled 'Cache'. So items come into my Inbox, and after 2 weeks, I would like them to be moved to 'Cache'. After 90 days of age, they will then be moved to an archive. Is this possible? I tried messing with rules, can couldn't figure out a way to do so.

Comment: What is powering your mailbox? Office 365? On-premise Exchange Server? Some other provider?

Comment: It is Office 365

Answer (score -1):

Yes, but it is not automatic. You can [create rules](https://blog.vishalon.net/move-outlook-emails-of-specific-date-range-to-a-folder) to move emails from a specific date range - that option is on Step 1 of the Rules Wizard towards the bottom. You can then run the rule you create manually on a periodic basis to move everything for you.

Comment: Yeah, I've tried that, but looking for a more automatic solution, so it continues to do this going forward without me having to change dates myself.